# Find distance between ArMarker and camera in ArToolkit's android java SDK

Tags: java, android, artoolkit

how to calculate distance betweeen smartphone camera and artoolkit marker.
i tried to get it from transformation matrix of marker but the vector value are all zero.

```
float [] pMatrix = ARToolKit.getInstance().getProjectionMatrix();
                float x = pMatrix[3];
                float y = pMatrix[7];
                float z = pMatrix[11];
```

x, y , z are all zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking at the wrong positions in the matrix. The camera x,y,z is inside the last column of the transformation matrix:

```
queryMarkerTransformation(int markerId);
Returns float array with 16 values. The values represent an OpenGL style transformation matrix.
The first 4 values represent the first column of the matrix.

i.e:
float[16] = [0.24218401, 0.9598883, 0.14125957, 0.0, -0.8614648, 0.2801126, -0.42357886, 0.0, -0.44614935, -0.019116696, 0.8947546, 0.0, 23.678268, -6.4265084, -298.65326, 1.0]

The matrix looks like:
0.24218401  -0.8614648  -0.44614935     23.678268
0.9598883   0.2801126   -0.019116696    -6.4265084
0.14125957  -0.42357886 0.8947546       -298.65326
0.0         0.0         0.0             1.0

The last column represents x,y,z in the camera coordinate system.
```

The source for that is here: https://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/tutorialcamera.htm I believe. (But somehow I cannot reach the url right now)

Now you are also reading the projection matrix, not the transformation matrix. 
(https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/blob/master/AndroidStudioProjects/ARSimpleProj/aRSimple/src/main/java/org/artoolkit/ar/samples/ARSimple/SimpleRenderer.java#L98)

If I tracked that down correctly value [14] should give you the distance to the marker.

Update:
I just wrote down a more detailed explanation here:
http://augmentmy.world/artoolkit-distance-between-camera-and-marker

Comment: thank you very much,it solved my problem, indeed i was looking at the wrong values.