# artoolkit Distance between camera and ArMarker

Tags: java, android, artoolkit

I want to find the accurate distance between camera and armarker.

```
float[] markerDistance = ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerTransformation(markerID.get(i));

float x = markerDistance[12];
float y = markerDistance[13];
float z = markerDistance[14];

double distance = Math.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));
```

Here is the distance but it is not accurate.

My project depends on accurate or nearly accurate distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered that before. The distance is represented by the z-Axis on ARToolKit5. Have a look here:

[Find distance between ArMarker and camera in ArToolkit's android java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484703/find-distance-between-armarker-and-camera-in-artoolkits-android-java-sdk/40494430#40494430)

Let me know it that is what you were looking for.

Comment: glad that it helped you. If it solves your issue please mark the answer as correct, thanks.